# Angular Directive to overwrite the parameters of another directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have an existing directive, which I don't want to touch, which is used like this:

```
<div other-directive value="xyz"></div>
```

The problem is, that the directive expects many parameters and I don't want to write them everytime. So my idea was to add a further directive, which sets these parameters upfront.

```
<div my-directive other-directive></div>
```

My overwrite mechanism looks like this:

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .directive("otherDirective", function(){
    return {
        restrict: "EA",
        template: '<i>{{value}}</i>',
        scope: {
            value: "=value"
        }
    };
  })

  // overwrite "value" parameter
  .directive("myDirective", function(){
    return {
        priority: 1000,
        restrict: "A",
        link: function(scope, element, attributes) {
          attributes.value = "Hello";
          attributes.$set('value', 'Hello');
        }
    };
  });
```

The second directive does not seem to be able to change the parameter for the first directive.
Please see my Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/HutmraGNm9U1RKl5OD2S?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code above won't work because of directive life cycle. Among directive functions `link` is the last thing to execute, `other-directive` has been already compiled at this moment. Instead, it should be

```
compile: function(element, attributes) {
  attributes.value = "Hello";
  attributes.$set('value', 'Hello');
}
```

By the way, `=` binding will result in empty value, because there's no `Hello` property on the scope. It likely should be `@`.

However, it is a hack. The idiomatic way to do this is to wrap `other-directive` with another directive and provide the desirable attributes in template.

Comment: Thank you - with "compile" it works! How can I "provide the attributes in template"?

Comment: A wrapper directive like `template: '<div other-directive value="xyz">'`. Unless nested tags or scopes cause problems, this is the way to go.